# Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему когда вызываю функцию send_email(), по более 100 раз повторно одно и то же на почту отправляет, а не один раз?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
else:
    if '.194.254' in output:
        for line in ip_mac_lines:
            if '0100' not in line:
                ok = line.split()
                f = operator.itemgetter(1)
                okk = str(f(ok))
                okk = okk.replace("'", "")
                okk = re.sub(r'[\(\)]', '', str(okk))
                okk = okk.replace(".", "")
                if '01' in okk:
                    okk = okk[2:]
                    with open('DHCP_pool.txt', 'a') as file:
                         file.write(okk + '\n')
                    connection.send_command('clear ip dhcp binding *')
                    with open('DHCP_pool.txt', 'r') as file:
                         END = file.read()
                         send_email(f"В магазине {hostname} забился пул ip-адресов: \n{END}")
```

Comment: Ну у вас же цикл, если внутри цикла условие сработает несколько раз, то и send_mail выполнится несколько раз. Нужно смотреть какие в у вас входные данные (ouput, ip_mac_lines), тогда можно будет что-то посоветовать.

Comment: 84:ss:c6:65:11:b0 
84:3d:c6:6v:12:20
84:3d:w6:65:w1:d4
40:83:we:32:18:02
dc:53:rr:2f:hh:65
40:83:de:af:ss:31
40:83:de:ww:be:74
40:83:qf:af:63:3c
88:46:70:29:f6:18
40:83:de:og:96:60

Comment: там мак адреса. Задача такая: Пройти по более 500 коммутаторам, с помощью команды sh ip dhcp binding, далее если на коммутаторе если найдется .194.254 то это значит что пул забит. Далее я должен оттуда убрать все и оставить только нужно мак адреса и это список который находится внутри "okk" отправить на почту.  У меня также отдельно создана функция которая, если вызвать есть то отправить на почту письмо.

Comment: Все уточнения добавьте в сам вопрос.